# Install MongoDB with Visual Studio 2010 Visual Studio Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mongodb, installation, windows-installer

We've got a Silverlight project in VS2010 and it has a web setup project with a custom action but now we need to include mongodb as part of the installation.  I can add the files from mongodb simply enough, but I'm not sure how to get it registered as a windows service and start it without using some sort of hack like trying to run the sc or InstallUtil command from a shell command or something.

Trial and error and googling hasn't yielded any results yet. Does anybody know how this can be done?

Comment: Just a caution that you understand the licensing of MongoDB and the requirements of their license if you want to distribute MongoDb with your application anything but "in-house": http://blog.mongodb.org/post/103832439/the-agpl.

Answer (score 0):

VS setups support service installation through .NET installer classes (same thing as installutil), otherwise I'd investigate if that mongodb service has a command line install. Many Win32 Windows Services supply a command line install parameter that installs them, so you would run the as a custom action to install it, and there'd also be an uninstall command. You might find an SC command to do it.

VS setups don't support the built-in capability of Windows Installer to install services. If you have the time, look at migrating to some other tool because VS setups are going away anyway.

This might be useful:
http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/tips.htm
and scroll down to "Installing Services with Visual Studio"